# Async/await simple example

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Im trying to understand the basics of async/await by creating a simple example.
Im using Sqlite with an Async connection and I have a class like this:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Now lets say that I want to save a `User` to my UserTable and when the saving is done I wish to retrieve it.

```
public async ? SaveToDb()
        {
            _conn.CreateTableAsync<User>();
            await _conn.InsertAsync(new User(){Id=1, Name = "Bill"});

            //Code that waits for the save to complete and then retrieves the user
        }
```

I suspect that I need a task somewhere, but im not completely sure how to do this. Thank you

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx http://www.dotnetperls.com/async http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/async-and-await bunch of example you can look into.

Comment: I doubt async/await for C# could be around as long as it has without examples of it in many places. As linked by @Vinod, a simple search would have found you these examples and many more.

Comment: You'll want to also await `CreateTableAsync` before awaiting `InsertAsync`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mostly there already.

When returning `void`:

```
public async Task SomethingAsync()
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

When returning a result:

```
public async Task<string> SomethingAsync()
{
    return await DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

The thing to note when returning a value in an async method is that you return the inner type (i.e in this case `string`) rather than a `Task<string>` instance.

Comment: Erm...You should really just do `return DoSomethingAsync();` and drop the `async` from the sig.

Comment: @Aron Not if he's awaiting within the method IIRC?

Comment: No. `DoSomethingAsync()` already returns a `Task`. So you don't need the compiler to unwrap the `Task` `await` it, then wrap the result in another `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

If your code doesn't return any value, the signature should be this, returning `Task`:

```
public async Task SaveToDb()
```

Else, you would need to specify the return type as the type argument in `Task<T>`, `string` in this sample:

```
public async Task<string> SaveToDb()
```